# Simple Contact form that writes to text file from html

Tags: javascript, php, html

What I have done so far is built a java based webserver using eclipse. I am able to access an index.html page i created. Now I am trying to create a contact form where a user can enter information and on submit it writes to and amends a text file, clears the form and shows the data users have submitted at the bottom of the page any suggestions.

Note: As per a request I edited this post to include code.

```
<?php
$saving = $_REQUEST['saving'];
if ($saving == 1){ 
$data = $_POST['data'];
$file = "data.txt"; 

$fp = fopen($file, "w") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

fclose($fp); 
echo "Saved to $file successfully!";

}
?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="data.php?saving=1">
<textarea name="data" cols="100" rows="10">
Name: 
Address: 
Email: 
Phone: 
---------------------------------------------
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
<p>

<a href="data.txt"><b>VIEW<b></a>
```

Comment: please add some code for reference

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Submit Data</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<form id="input" action="test.php" method="get">
Comment: <input type="text" name="Comments">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Not here man put it the Question and also put your php code which you have used.

Comment: I added the php code to the question. Any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated some of your html too so please check that too.
What you was doing it was rewriting the whole file again and again in this code that bug is removed.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $writeComment = implode('', file('test.txt')) . '[!@X#$]'. $_POST['data'];
    $myfile = fopen("test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

    fwrite($myfile, rtrim($writeComment, '[!@X#$]'));
    fclose($myfile);
}

$fileContent = implode('', file('test.txt'));
$comments = explode('[!@X#$]', rtrim($fileContent, '[!@X#$]'));

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Submit Data</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="input" action="" method="post">
        Comment: <textarea name="data" cols="100" rows="10">
            Name: 
            Address: 
            Email: 
            Phone: 
            ---------------------------------------------
        </textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ($comments as $i => $comment) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Comment(<?php echo ($i + 1)?>):
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $comment;?>
            </tr>
        </td>
        <?php }?>
    </table>
    <a href="test.txt">View Core File</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see how you edited and trying to understand.  From the <!Doctype html>  is my main index.html. I was trying to understand how to divide the rest of the code cause i am presuming that does not go in to the index.html file. I am a novice so i need more direction in advance thank you.

Comment: I am still having problems and not able to make it work.

Comment: Sorry Michael i can't understand your need i thing you need to ask questions come over skype of something because this is not the right place for this.